Connect to SQL Server using Windows Authentication on MacOS
How do I connect to SQL Server using Windows Authentication using a different domain account other than the one I used to login to the computer?
If I were using a Windows PC, to run as a different Windows domain user, I can usually run the program, e.g., SSMS.exe, using runas /netonly or use Windows Credential Manager to specify their domain account and password for each server/host.y
When I check on the server side, this is the error that is recorded on the SQL Server error log.

Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 58.
Login failed for user ''. Reason: An attempt to login using SQL authentication failed. Server is configured for Integrated authentication only. [CLIENT: nnn.nnn.nnn.nnn]

On MacOS (Apple Silicon), is there a way to connect using Windows Authentication using any client app, e.g., Azure Data Studio or DBeaver? Can you please provide screenshots when possible.
On DBeaver, which is available to MacOS users, I see various other methods like Active Directory (Integrated/MFA/MSI/Password) but none seems to work as expected and I get this error on the server side when I test.

Is your MacOS device joined to a (Windows) domain?

Is your Mac domain joined, or otherwise have Kerberos installed? See eg https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/deployment/depe6a1cda64/web

Hello, it is not joined. I am actually going to post a workaround I found in DBeaver, which I just stumbled upon recently, but I am only allowed 1 post every 30 min. Thanks.

Found this post helpful from user siick and I can now use my domain user to connect to SQL Server.
Basically, do not put the domain, e.g., "YourCompanyDomainName\" in the DBeaver Username field.
Instead, go to Driver properties tab and indicate the domain there on the field called domain.
DBeaver: Use Windows authentication from linux to connect SQL Server
